# Retrieve func_code from builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to retrieve the func_code object from a builtin_function_or_method?
ie from time.time()

```
import time
dir(time.time)
```

doesn't contain the function object

nor does

```
dir(time.time.__call__)
```

that just returns itself

```
time.time.__call__.__call__.__call__
```

..and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably because builtin functions are implemented in C and therefore have no Python code. Not sure enough to post this as an answer though.

Comment: You could try it on PyPy.

Comment: anything implemented in C doesn't have a `func_code`, so no, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CPython, built-in methods are implemented in C (or some other language, e.g. C++), so it is not possible to get a `func_code` (that attribute exists only for functions defined using Python).

You can find the source code of `time.time` here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.5/Modules/timemodule.c#l126

Other Python implementations may make `func_code` available on built-in functions. For example, on PyPy:

```
$ pypy
Python 2.7.1 (7773f8fc4223, Nov 18 2011, 22:15:49)
[PyPy 1.7.0 with GCC 4.0.1] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import time
>>>> time.time
<built-in function time>
>>>> time.time.func_code
<builtin-code object at 0x00000001017422e0>
>>>> time.time.func_code.co_consts
('time() -> floating point number\n\n    Return the current time in seconds since the Epoch.\n    Fractions of a second may be present if the system clock provides them.',)
```

Comment: Don't work in python 3[]
`>>> import time
>>> time.time.funct_code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#167>", line 1, in <module>
    time.time.funct_code
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'funct_code'`

Comment: Python 3 uses `__code__` instead of `func_code`. However, it still won't have that attribute on built-in functions. PyPy3, on the other hand, will have `__code__ ` defined on some built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can't. [From the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Built-in functions
>
> A built-in function object is a wrapper around a C function. Examples of built-in functions are `len()` and `math.sin()` (`math` is a standard built-in module). The number and type of the arguments are determined by the C function. Special read-only attributes: `__doc__` is the function’s documentation string, or None if unavailable; `__name__` is the function’s name; `__self__` is set to `None` (but see the next item); `__module__` is the name of the module the function was defined in or `None` if unavailable.

These are compiled C code - there's no representation of the function body in Python code.